# Sprite leaves duplicates when I move it

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have been learning online and used various tutorials to draw a sprite in a pygame window. I am now trying to have it move a set number of pixels across a screen (dependant on the number returned from a diceroll).

```
def diceroll():
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(roll)
    playerCar.move_piece_hoz((WIDTH / 13) * roll)


def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:  # a while loop to run the game out of, it sets the clock speed and also consistently checks if
        # user ever quits
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                diceroll()

        # checks any updates to the array of sprites
        all_sprites_list.update()

        # draws all our sprites in their respective positions
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        # Refresh Screen
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

there is the relevant code , I essentially want it so whenever the player presses the left mouse button it calls the dice roll function that will then pick a random number of pieces across a board. However , whenever I press the left mouse button the sprite basically remains in it's current position and a new duplicate copy is drawn where it should be going. I have attached an image in-case there is any confusion as to what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IRzN.png). The sprite is the red square.

If I call the function manually by using : diceroll() by itself , outside of the main() function. The sprite is redrawn correctly with no issues and without leaving a duplicate , however  that way I can only call it once which is not what I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object.
When you draw something on a *Surface*, the pixel data stored in the *Surface* object is changed. The entire scene is drawn anew in every frame. You need to clear the display or draw the background in every frame:

```py
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:  # a while loop to run the game out of, it sets the clock speed and also consistently checks if
        # user ever quits
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                diceroll()

        screen.fill(0) # <--- this is missing

        # checks any updates to the array of sprites
        all_sprites_list.update()

        # draws all our sprites in their respective positions
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        # Refresh Screen
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)